Is it possible to get protobuf enum value with spaces?
I would like to enum to have string values like: "value one", "value two"
What it the best way to get these string values from
enum MyValueType
{
    VALUE_ONE = 0;
    VALUE_TWO = 1;
}


An enum definition cannot contain spaces.
enums essentially name numeric values using constants and names cannot contain spaces.
The solution to your problem is:

Optionally (recommeded): don't use Protobuf Messages directly in your application logic but provide a mapping between Messages and your application types; this provides better abstraction and avoids problems with e.g. serializing protobuf types.

Add FromString|ToString methods to your application types to convert enum constants to strings.


